# how to downgrade project from android2.2 to android 2.1 ?

Tags: android

I have my android project running on android 2.2 . I want it to work on android 2.1 .
How do I do that ??
Changing the target sdk in manifest file did not help .
I tried to clean the project but it deleted my R.java file. Plz suggest urgently.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse:

Right click on the project --> Properties 
- Click **Android** sub-section from the left panel 
- Change the **Target Name** to Android 2.1